# How-to add horizontal scroll bar to jquery.bootgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-bootgrid

I'm using jquery bootgrid to display some data (http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/), could anyone help to add horizontal scroll bar to this grid?

I tried to put it into div with overflow-x style, but it scrolls navigation and paging together.

If it not possible, could you recommend free grids for ASP .NET MVC with has this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the CSS class bootgrid-table with these :

```
display: block;
width: 50px;
overflow-x: scroll;
```

I set the width to 50px for a test, but it maybe could be left to what it is, 100%. Though, due to data collapsing with "...", not sure it would work appart removing this too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I removed width: 50px; аnd all work smooth!

Answer (score 3):

As you are already using Bootstrap, you can add the `table-responsive` class to the outer div of the table element

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">


   </table>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
  var dt = $('#myTable').bootgrid({
          selection: true,
          rowSelect: true,
          converters: {},
        });
});

</script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u5w4w24s/1/